# Is there a way to have the mat-checkbox checked if the box itself is checked?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a link in my checkbox and when I click the link it also checks the box. Is there a way to disable that? I don't want to remove the text outside the checkbox so if there's a way to do it that would be great.

```
<mat-checkbox>
Checkout this <a (click)="getLink('linkurl')">Link</a>.
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: First off, just wanted to comment that this is inadvisable as there are accessibility/interactivity implications to removing the default behavior of form control labels. With that said, do you want only the the text "Link" to not toggle the checkbox, or all of the text "Checkout this" as well as "Link"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to first flag this as inadvisable. [Anchors should not be placed inside of labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#interactive_content), and the ability to click on a label to toggle the checkbox input is by design, aiding people using touch screen devices and the like.

With that said, you can pass the `$event` argument to your event handler and call `.preventDefault()` which stops the default action.

```
(click)="getLink('linkurl', $event)
```

And in your component class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  getLink(linkurl: string, event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops the checkbox from being selected.
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I didn't know preventDefault until now

Answer (score 1):

You could add event.preventDefault() to your click event:

(click)="getLink('linkurl'); event.preventDefault()"